# Why SpriteKit's 'addChild' method result in chaos

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm in a trouble of SpriteKit's 'addChild' method.

I tried to add a simple button to my scene , and the button is formed of one background image and one label.So I wrote code like this:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let buttonBg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainButton_green")
    let buttonLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Label")

    self.addChild(buttonBg)
    self.addChild(buttonLabel)  
}
```

Then I ran the program on simulator and I found that result is strange.Sometimes it appeared right,like this:
[correct appearence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4WHH.png)

But sometimes, 'buttonLabel' will be behind of 'buttonBg', just like this:
[wrong appearence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI90o.png)

Why?

ps. I had print self.children , and the result was '[buttonBg,buttonLabel]' in each situation , my skview.ignoresSiblingOrder was always false.

Comment: what version of XCode, iOS, and device are you testing on?

Comment: also, is there any other code to this?  something may be changing the results of your children after your print statement.

Comment: Your problem may just be related to the simulator, since it is only a simulator, not an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can do

```
let buttonBg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainButton_green")
buttonBg.zPosition = 1

let buttonLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Label")
buttonLabel.zPosition = 2
```

which manually sets the z layering of your objects

I also think that if you are creating a button object you should add the label as a child of the background

```
let buttonBg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainButton_green")
buttonBg.zPosition = 1

let buttonLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Label")
buttonLabel.zPosition = 1

self.addChild(buttonBg)
buttonBg.addChild(buttonLabel)
```

I always add a zPosition even if its the only child.

Comment: thanks a lot.By the way ,the first way you said is effective , but it will be a troublesome thing if you are working on a complex game, and the second way still have problem , the label will be behind of the background sometimes...

Comment: I've made very complex games, it's not troublesome if you make it a habit. You are incorrect the label will never be behind the background if you add it as a child of the background. If you wanted it to be behind the background you would use a negative zPosition (-1)

Comment: his issue is very weird, since the results should be deterministic, thus consistent.

Comment: agreed, but I don't think that there is enough info in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not a real problem: when you create your elements, following your case they'll be rendered in the main thread following some rules like:

- *statements order*
- *`zPosition` property*
- *`alpha` property*
- etc..

So, something like a litlle `label` could be drawed **before** your button background causing this annoying aspect.

A good thing to do **when you want to create a button** should be:

```
let buttonBg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainButton_green")
self.addChild(buttonBg)
let buttonLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Label")
buttonBg.addChild(buttonLabel)
```

In other words, put your label **as a child** of your background, this should will guarantee to you a correct `zPosition` levels (without change `zPosition` properties), a correct `label` position  (by default `CGPoint.zero`) always if you haven't changed (leave untouched) the `anchorPoint` of your elements.